# How to print start time and end time on excel using Python?

Tags: python, excel, time

The goal is to print the start time on the excel sheet and once the code execution has completed it will print the end time. How is that done? I am using the below code but the start time and end time are exactly the same down to the milliseconds.

`import xlsxwriter`

`import datetime`

`now = datetime.datetime.now()`

`time = (now.strftime("%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S"))`

`worksheet1.write('H1', f'Start Time: {now}')`

`.`

`.`

`.`

`code running for several minutes.  Many if functions`

`.`

`.`

`.`

`worksheet1.write('H2', f'End Time: {now}')`

Output:

Start Time: 2021-03-25 20:49:42.493027

End Time:   2021-03-25 20:49:42.493027

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that at both the times , before and after your code runs, you are writing the start time to the excel sheet. You could try updating the 'now' variable to reflect the end execution time after the code runs.

```py
import xlsxwriter
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()

time = (now.strftime("%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S"))

worksheet1.write('H1', f'Start Time: {now}')

'''
your code
'''

now = datetime.datetime.now() # note
time = (now.strftime("%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S"))
worksheet1.write('H2', f'End Time: {now}')
```